# Timeout in locking /.Xauthority

Tags: linux, ssh, root, x11, xauth

I have google searched and everyone who has this problem has an error in locking /home/user/.Xauthority.  The issue is that it is trying to lock /.Xauthority.  Obviously there is no .Xauthority in /, and even if there was it would not be accessible to a user.  This problem is only occuring with one user, all other users work fine.  What should I check?  Here's what happens:

```
[root@box dir]# ssh USER@HOST
USER@HOSTS's password: 
Last login: Thu Jul 25 10:09:19 2013 from OTHER_HOST
(30 sec later)
/usr/bin/xauth:  timeout in locking authority file /.Xauthority
```

Comment: Check out [this similar question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/215558/22734) on the Unix Stack Exchange

Answer (score 0):

Check that your user actually has a valid home directory, which exists and is accessible by that user. This error indicates that the user's home directory is set to `/`, which is not going to be valid.

Comment: Yes the user has a valid home directory.

Comment: I can't even do a normal ssh into there without X11 forwarding.  It connects and just closes.

Comment: My contexts and perms on my home dir are the same as other users who can login (different name of course)